# Como usar o method="GET'' sem o action

Tags: url, get, url-amigável

Estou criando um mini-sistema de busca, o  problema é que quero usar o `method="get"` sem usar o `action=""` e ao mesmo tempo conseguir colocar `css` na página sem usar o `action`. Desejo evitar o uso do `action` por este motivo:

```
www.meusite.com/index.html?q=sua+busca+aqui
```

sendo, que desejo essa `URL`:

```
www.meusite.com/Pesquisar?q=sua+busca+aqui
```

É o principal colocar algo dentro do `get` como arquivos de design, scripts e html, pois quando executamos o `method="get"` ele necessita de um arquivo para reproduzi-lo na página. Mas o meu caso é conseguir colocar algo dentro do `get` sem o `action` e deixar a `url` sem o nome do arquivo.

Caso não seja possível, como fazer para que o nome do arquivo não apareça na `url`, exemplo:

Documento visível na url:

```
www.meusite.com/index.html?q=sua+busca+aqui
```

Gostaria de deixar no lugar do documento só o "?p=" ou "Pesquisar?p=" ou "p="

```
www.meusite.com/Pesquisar?p=uma+pesquisa+idiota
```

Comment: Se o seu web server for apache vc precisa usar o mod_rewrite para ter url amigaveis.
Depois disso vc pode usar essa url com o get tranquilamente, ex:
<form action="www.meusite.com/Pesquisar" method="GET">
<input name="p">...

Comment: Eu não entendi, o que o css tem haver com `action`. O action é só o endereço que apontará para requisição e css é algo que vai no header ou corpo da página, uma coisa não tem nada haver com a outra. Explica melhor porque tá muito confuso.

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente não use `action=""`, use somente `<form method="get">`.

Dessa forma ficará `www.meusite.com/?p=uma+pesquisa`, se ainda quiser ter uma url mais amigável, precisará utilizar o mod_rewrite.